# This instance of (MS) SQL Server has been using a process id of X since dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql-server

I was looking through the SQL Server logs and come across the following informational message.

> This instance of SQL Server has been using a process ID of 1960 since 12/10/2014 20:02:48 (UTC). This is an information message only: no user action is required.

This message has been generated for the last three days. I cannot see the process-id using the activity monitor.

Is this something that may cause/highlight a problem that I need to look into?

Comment: I'm really not a friend of non-actionable spam log messages. SQL Server can be really chatty with the log.

Comment: Did you connect to SQL in management studio to view the logs? Then everything is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do you need to worry about this log message:

No, this is just an information message that SQL Server instance using a process id 1960, since SQL Server services are started (i.e. 12/10/2014 20:02:48 ) and for last 5 days instance is still running.

> How often this message is generated in log:

SQL Server creates a log entry for this message on each date change. So you can find one entry for each 24 hours.

> How to verify process id:

To verify this process id, open Windows Task Manager and move to “Processes” tab, click on “View” in menu, “Select Columns”. Select PID (Process Identifier). Now it will start showing process identifier for each process. Check process identifier for sqlserver.exe

Details from my blog: http://www.connectsql.com/2012/06/sql-server-log-this-instance-of-sql.html

Answer (score 7):

No, this is perfectly normal, as the message says. It is just SQL Server's way of telling you the pid.

To verify, within SQL Server you can do `select serverproperty('processid')`, and then in the OS space you should be able to check the process ID like this in a one-liner PowerShell command:

```
Get-Process "sqlservr"
```

Comment: +1 This is much better answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the log, "This is an information message only: no user action is required."

You can't see that PID in the SQL Server activity monitor: it's a PID that you can see in the Windows Task Manager (if you tick "show processes from all users")